# Bash: Convert absolute URL to relative

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I have a list of absolute URLs and want to filter the front part. E.g. http://www.domain.tld/example turns to /example

This part is saved in the variable `domain=www.domain.tld`. Without http, obvious.

My code after several attempts is (with escaped dots because of regex): `grep -o -v "http://${domain//./\\.}"`

It doesn't work very well ... Anyone up with a solution? Maybe sleek awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all URLs contain the protocol, you can use `cut` with `/` as delimiter and print from the 4th field:

```
cut -d'/' -f4- file
```

#### Test

```
$  cat a
http://www.domain.tld/example 
http://www.another.doma.in/and/therest
$ cut -d'/' -f4- a
example 
and/therest
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Super simple solution. I will remember `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
domain='domain.tld'
```

to allow for both `www.domain.tld` and `domain.tld` in URL.

Then use this `gnu-grep` command:

```
grep -oP "https?://(www\.)?$domain\K/\S*" file
/example
```

- `https?` - will match both `http` and `https`
- `(www\.)?` - will make `www.` optional before `$domain` variable
- `\K` - is used for match reset in PCRE regex to discard matched information upto that point
- `-o` - will output only matched text
- `-P` - is used for `PCRE` regex in `grep`